# Uncheck all checkboxes in a TCheckListBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I want the user to be able to press a button to reset a TCheckListBox to it's initial state (having no boxes checked).

See images below of an example of what I want to happen after clicking the button:

[image: Multiple checked boxes in a TCheckBoxList]

Changed to:

[image: No boxes are checked]

How would I go about doing this? I know there would probably be a loop involved, but I'm unsure where to start. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nice method - look at official help.

If we open TCheckListBox help page, choose Methods and filter off "inherited" ones, we'll see [CheckAll method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.CheckLst.TCheckListBox.CheckAll)

```
CheckListBox1.CheckAll(cbUnchecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

*For individual checkboxes* (missed this is a TCheckListBox).

Something along these lines,

Let's assume the checkboxes are on a panel called `panel1`.

```pascal
var n: Integer;
begin
  for n := 0 to panel1.ComponentCount - 1 do 
     if panel1.Components[n] is TCheckbox then 
        Tcheckbox(panel1.components[n]).checked := False;
end;
```

Note: if there is an event associated with the checkbox, you need to set the event to nil before modifying it, and returning the event after - else, the event will trigger as if you clicked the box.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I can delete if the answer is confusing here.

Comment: JFTR, there is a protected property _ClicksDisabled_ that prohibits the _OnClick_ event being executed when _Checked_ is set.